# Count number of adjacent pairs in Binary

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

Let's say that I'm given an integer n, which is read from the user.

I would like to count the number of adjacent pairs of 1's that is has.

So for example, let's say I'm given the number 31.

The binary representation of 31 is 11111.

The number of pairs would be 11 11 1 => 2 pairs

How would you do this using bitwise operators?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt(s) work or not work? Please create a [mcve] of your attempt and show it to us, describing the problems you have with it. Also please read or refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the integer with the `((n&3)==3)` condition to find an adjacent pairs in bit position 0 and 1. If pair found we shift to right by 2 otherwise by 1 until we did not check all of the 32 bits.

```
   unsigned int n = 31;  /* input */
   unsigned char number_of_pairs = 0;  /* result */
   unsigned char mask_position = 0;
   do
   {
      if(((n >> mask_position) & 3) == 3)
      {
         number_of_pairs += 1;
         mask_position += 2;
      }
      else
      { 
         mask_position += 1;
      }
   } while(mask_position < 32);
```

Comment: "babud", This is a mostly working but not finally thought out solution. The OP might have learned more and faster if she had tried it herself. SO is more about helping on specific issues and not a coding service. ;-)